# How to block REST services to anonymous users (ESRI)

Tags: asp.net, rest, gis, esri

Is there an efficient way to block REST services to anonymous users?

I am running a website in `ASP.NET 4.0` where people log in and according to their credentials they have access to different maps. I would like to avoid having them log in again.

The `ESRI WebAdaptor` is only running in `ASP.NET 2.0` and I'm having a real hard time making it work with the rest of the website.  I am not a web guru at all, just inherited this project lucky me.

Thank you for any suggestions or ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

We had to deal with this issue within our organisation as well. We used an Apache load balancer as a reverse-proxy solution so that only authenticated user's requests to REST services were redirected.
This was the most reasonable solution in our case but you might look into ArcGIS Server token service:

[Securing Internet connections to services](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Securing_Internet_connections_to_services/0093000000q4000000/)

Which version of AGS are You using?